# Can you export an SSRS tablix with row and column groups into separate sheets in excel?

Tags: excel, ssrs-tablix

I have a tablix that has row groups by employee and a column group by state -- and the grid shows amounts from each state for each employee. I'm looking for a way to export the data to excel such that I have all employees in the row group on each sheet but only show the income for each state separately. Basically, we need to use the column group by option to insert page breaks and export to excel.

I tried creating a subreport inside a rectangle for each state that calls the main report and manually pass each state as a hard coded parameter and it works for small datasets without any issues. But I'm running into memory issues on big data sets and looking for an alternative way to solve this problem. I've read about a parent row group with an "In Between" page break but I'm not sure how I can keep the row and column groups intact for each state.

```
Main Report
---------------------------
       State 1   State 2
---------------------------
John|   100       200
---------------------------
Jane|   300       400
---------------------------
```

Export should look like this:

Sheet Name: State 1

```
       State 1
--------------
John|   100
--------------
Jane|   300    
--------------
```

Sheet Name: State 2

```
       State 2
--------------
John|   200
--------------
Jane|   400    
--------------
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!